# app with phonegap doesn't work. It doesn't get coordinates

Tags: cordova, coordinates

I have an app with phonegap, and it works (get coordinates) when I test it with Ripple Extension of Chrome.
But when I test it from movile devices, it doesn't get any coordinates...
I tested with HTC and Samsung Galaxy, and it doesn't get any coordinates...
What can cause this?
Thanks very much in advance, Daniel

**EDIT:**
There's a fiddle in a comment below. 
Using cordova-1.9.0.js , jquery-1.7.1.min.js , jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css and jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js

This is the part of code that fails, because when testing in mobile, it doesn't give back any coordinates (the app doesn't access onSuccess or onError functions):

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

```
var watchID = null;

    // PhoneGap ha cargado -> Llamada al objeto geolocation para localizar el dispositivo por GPS
    function onDeviceReady() {
    // Throw an error if no update is received every 1 seconds
    var options = { timeout: 1000 };
    watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
}
```

I just read in official documentation of phonegap this: *The Android 2.x simulators will not return a geolocation result unless the enableHighAccuracy option is set to true.*
It could be my problem, but I'm testing in real mobile android devices, not in simulators...This is the link I read: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation at the end *Android Quirks*

Comment: check if u r gps service is running on your device. Cant help without seein any code. plz create a fiddle.

Comment: Hello friend, I'm going to create a fiddle right now. Wait one minute please...

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/342Pn/

Comment: Maybe is there any problem with watchPosition?